# How to deal with nameless forms on websites?

Tags: perl, forms, web, automation

I would like to write a script that lets me use this website

http://proteinmodel.org/AS2TS/LGA/lga.html

(I need to use it a few hundred times, and I don't feel like doing that manually)

I have searched the internet for ways how this could be done using Perl, and I came across `WWW::Mechanize`, which seemed to be just what I was looking for. But now I have discovered that the form on that website which I want to use has no name - its declaration line simply reads

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="./lga-form.cgi" ENCTYPE=multipart/form-data>
```

At first I tried simply not setting  my `WWW::Mechanize` object's `form_name` property, which gave me this error message when I provided a value for the form's email address field:

```
Argument "my_email@address.com" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at /usr/share/perl5/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 1618.
```

I then tried setting `form_name` to `''` and later `' '`, but it was to no avail, I simply got this message:

```
There is no form named " " at ./automate_LGA.pl line 40
```

What way is there to deal with forms that have no names? It would be most helpful if someone on here could answer this question - even if the answer points away from using `WWW::Mechanize`, as I just want to get the job done, (more or less) no matter how.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the answer. I can address the nameless form by its number (there's just one form on the webpage, so I guessed it would be number `1`, and it worked). Here's part of my code:

```
my $lga = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $address = 'my_email@address.com';
my $options = '-3 -o0 -d:4.0';
my $pdb_2   = "${pdb_id}_1 ${pdb_id}_2";

$lga->get('http://proteinmodel.org/AS2TS/LGA/lga.html');
$lga->success or die "LGA GET fail\n";

$lga->form_number(1);
$lga->field('Address', $address);
$lga->field('Options', $options);
$lga->field('PDB_2', $pdb_2);
$lga->submit();
$lga->success or die "LGA POST fail\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

An easy and more robust way is to use the [$mech->form_with_fields()](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Eform_with_fields(_@fields_)) method from [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) to select the form you want based on the fields it contains.

Easier still, use the `submit_form` method with the `with_fields` option.

For instance, to locate a form which has fields named 'username' and 'password', complete them and submit the form, it's as easy as:

```
$mech->submit_form( 
    with_fields => { username => $username, password => $password }
);
```

Doing it this way has the advantage that if they shuffle their HTML around, changing the order of the forms in the HTML, or adding a new form before the one you're interested in, your code will continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `WWW::Mechanize`, but its Python equivalent, [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), gives you an array of forms that you can iterate even if you don't know their names.

Example (taken from its homepage):

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")

for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

**EDIT:** searching in the docs of `WWW::Mechanize` I found the [$mech->forms() method](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Eforms%28%29), that could be what you need. But since I don't know perl or `WWW::Mechanize`, I'll leave there my python answer.